# I need to find second element with the same automationid by Xpath

Tags: c#, wpf, selenium, testing, xpath

I'm struggling with finding by Xpath. My problem is that the software that I'm testing has one specific function where I need to scan two components (is it called two-step scan) and there are two textboxes without the name and with the same Automationid. So I need to find the second one I tried this but it does not work.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Xpath, Using = "//*[@AutomationId='ScanTextBox'][1]")]
public IWebElement ScanTextBox1;

[FindsBy(How = How.Xpath, Using = "//*[@AutomationId='ScanTextBox'][2]")]
public IWebElement ScanTextBox2;
```

I'm using winium and I'm testing WPF application.

Comment: What error do you see with **`(How = How.Xpath, Using = "//*[@AutomationId='ScanTextBox'][2]")`**? Can you update the relevant `HTML`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to use a `FindsBy`? We are unable to create a correct XPath to a FindsBy to these buttons without the html. This way, I only can provide you another solution, and update my awnser when the html code be provided.

You can use `FindElement`, the plural one, that is able to return both. After, you select the desired button by index. A example method able to do it:

```
public IWebElement GetScanTextBox(int index)
{
    return Driver
        .FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@AutomationId='ScanTextBox']"))
        .ElementAt(index);
}

public void UsageExample()
{
    var buttonOne = GetScanTextBox(0);
    var buttonTwo = GetScanTextBox(1);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update locators as described here:

```
(//*[@AutomationId='ScanTextBox'])[1]
(//*[@AutomationId='ScanTextBox'])[2]
```

The difference is that in my case `(locator)[n]`you select `n-th` element out of all elements found by a locator. And by`locator[n]` you search for element that has `n-th` positions  inside parent nodes

Comment: Apparently this should nail the OP